Sumifs in SQL with dates filters
I am trying to write a query to produce a new table which will sum ifs the 'gross amount' from existing table (say A) when the following conditions meet:

if reporting date is less than or equal to A. reporting date

and deposit date is greater than reporting date'


that is, I want the sum of all the deposit for a single reporting date which have been received after the date has passed. (see the desired results in table B)
Table A:



Reporting_date
id
deposit_date
gross_amount




2023-12-31
tr-9
2024-04-19
6000


2023-09-30
tr-9
2024-01-31
4000


2023-06-30
tr-9
2023-10-02
5000


2023-03-31
tr-9
2023-07-24
3000


2022-12-31
tr-9
2023-03-24
2000


2022-09-30
tr-9
2022-12-23
1000


2022-06-30
tr-9
2022-10-12
500



Expected result
Table B:



reporting_date
deposits
Logic
gross_amount




12/31/2023
10000
'6000 +4000
6000


9/30/2023
9000
'4000 +5000
4000


6/30/2023
8000
'5000 +3000
5000


3/31/2023
3000
'3000
3000


12/31/2022
2000
'2000
2000


9/30/2022
1500
'1000 +500
1000


6/30/2022
500
'500
500



SQL code
Select
    a.id,
    a.reporting_date,
    (sum(a.gross_amount) ) as deposits 
from Table A
where reporting_date <=  A.reporting_date and A.deposit_date > reporting_date
group by A.id, A.reporting_date


So what is your question here? You've told us what you want, and shown us your code, but not asked anything.

the code is not generating the expected results...so wanted to understand where I am going wrong

Please use below query
select M.reporting_date,SUM(L.gross_amount)deposits,String_AGG(L.gross_amount,'+') Logic,M.gross_amount
from #Test M  
LEFT JOIN #Test L ON M.reporting_date >= L.reporting_date AND M.Reporting_date<L.deposit_date
GROUP BY M.reporting_date,M.gross_amount
order by M.Reporting_date desc



A good answer includes an explanation

@SantoshSingh - I would suggest adding a WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ...) to guarantee a consistent ordering of the Logic components.  Also, to handle multiple accounts, id should be added to the join condition, group-by, and order-by.  Also, as Dale pointed out, including an explanation of your answer is good practice. Posting code-only answers is discouraged.

I think you are trying this to code !!
select a.id, a.reporting_date, sum(b.gross_amount) as deposits 
from report a 
inner join report b 
on a.id=b.id 
where  b.reporting_date<=a.reporting_date and b.deposit_date>a.reporting_date 
group by a.id, a.reporting_date;


A good answer includes an explanation

True. totally agree but like Thom A said, I am not able to understand the requirements and what he actually asked. But from query I thought that he might be trying "Self Join" and SQL could help him little bit.

Well firstly you should only answer a question when you do understand the requirements. And secondly you should still explain what your does and how it might solve OPs problem.
